# Typeorm oneToMany Column type for # is not defined

Tags: node.js, typeorm

I just trying to query a OneToMany related entities but, in this query, i need to show data attendance inside result data employee. but i always get issue like this :

> ColumnTypeUndefinedError: Column type for Attendance#employee is not defined and cannot be guessed. Make sure you have turned on an "emitDecoratorMetadata": true option in tsconfig.json. Also make sure you have imported "reflect-met
> adata" on top of the main entry file in your application (before any entity imported).If you are using JavaScript instead of TypeScript you must explicitly provide a column type.

and i already change : `"emitDecoratorMetadata": true,`

Here my entity :

```
import {
    Column,
    CreateDateColumn,
    Entity,
    JoinColumn,
    ManyToOne,
    OneToMany,
    OneToOne,
    PrimaryGeneratedColumn,
} from 'typeorm';
import {Employee} from "../Users/Employee/employee.entity";
import {MAttendanceStatus} from "./m_attendance_status.entity";
import {MShift} from "../Master/m_shift.entity";
import 'reflect-metadata';


@Entity('r_attendance')
export class Attendance {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id: number;

    @Column({ name: 'created_at', nullable: true })
    created_at: Date;

    @ManyToOne(() => Employee, (employee) => employee.id, { onDelete: 'CASCADE' })
    @JoinColumn({ name: 'id_employee' })
    @Column({ name: 'id_employee', nullable: true })
    employee: Employee;

    @Column({ name: 'date', nullable: true, type: 'date' })
    date: string;

    @Column({ name: 'in', nullable: true })
    in: string;

    @Column({ name: 'out', nullable: true })
    out: string;

    @Column({ name: 'is_overtime', nullable: true })
    isOvertime: boolean;
}
```

And :

```
import {
  Column,
  CreateDateColumn,
  Entity,
  JoinColumn,
  ManyToOne,
  OneToMany,
  OneToOne,
  PrimaryGeneratedColumn,
} from 'typeorm';
import {Attendance} from "../../Reporting/attendance.entity";
import 'reflect-metadata';

@Entity('employee')
export class Employee {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @Column({ name: 'created_at', nullable: true })
  created_at: Date;

  @Column({ name: 'code', length: 80, nullable: true })
  code: string;

  @Column({ name: 'name', length: 150, nullable: true })
  name: string;

  @OneToMany(() => Attendance, (Attendance) => Attendance.employee)
  attendances: Attendance[];
}
```

Here's what I want :

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Adam P",
    "attendances": [{
            "id": 1,
            "created_at": "2022-07-25 29:12:09",
            "date": "2022-07-25",
            "id_employee": 1,
            "in": "08:00",
            "out": "12:00",
            "is_overtime": false
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "created_at": "2022-07-26 29:12:09",
            "date": "2022-07-26",
            "id_employee": 1,
            "in": "08:00",
            "out": "12:00",
            "is_overtime": false
        }
    ]
}
```

what do i have to do to make it work ?